# how to display the date at X axis and other column at y axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

My csv file looks like this
date,success,failure,count
2015-03-30,95,65,160
2015-03-31,10,8,18
2015-04-01,38,20,58
I have to display date at X axis .

My code looks like this what are the modifications i have to do please suggest me on this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>


        <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


        <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'statistics'
                },
                xAxis: {

                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'hits'
                    }
                },
                series: []
            };




            $.get('user_profile19.csv', function(data) 
            {
                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
                {
                    var items = line.split(',');

                    // header line containes categories
                    if (lineNo > 0) {

                        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) 

                        {
                            if (itemNo == 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                        });
                    }

                    // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                    else if(lineNo==0) {
                        var series = 
                        { 
                            data: []
                        };
                        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) 
                        {
                            if (itemNo == 0) 
                            {
                                series.name = item;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                        });

                        options.series.push(series);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                });

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });


        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="width: 800px; margin: 2em auto; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 0.5em">
            NOTE: This demo shows a way of manually parsing CSV. As of Highcharts 4.0 this is
            not necessary for simple CSV files, as this functionality is built into the 
            <a href="http://api.highcharts.com/#data">Data module</a>.
        </div>

        <!-- 3. Add the container -->
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some bugs in it.  First, it looks as though you intend to take the categories from the first row but then instead take it from all the other rows.
Then you're only taking the first item of each line, which is always the date, to create your categories.  Obviously this isn't what you want.

This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hibiscus/ec8gm8oq/ does what I believe you're trying to do.  The CSV data is just added as a variable to simplify things.  The relevant code is this:

```
var categoryIndex = 0;
var categories = [];

$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
            {                    
                var items = line.split(',');
                // header line containes categories

                if (lineNo == 0) {                        
                    for (var i=1; i < items.length; i++) {
                        categories.push(items[i]);
                    }
                }

                if (lineNo > 0) {   
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) 
                    {                            
                        if (itemNo == 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    });

                    var series = 
                    { 
                        data: []
                    };

                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) 
                    {                            
                        if (itemNo == 0) 
                        {
                            series.name = categories[categoryIndex++];
                        } 
                        else 
                        {                                                                                            
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                    });
                    options.series.push(series);
                }

            });
```

Comment: this is what I wanted,1)But if I display total success and total failure on some other day,currently it is getting displayed at 1-4-2015 date,  instead on the same day for example at  30-3-2015 only it has to display 
2)how can I display total_success,total_failure and the total count of the same date in stacked format graph
total count has to display.Please suggest me on this .

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but if you just want to have those values stacked for each day you simply need to add stacking: true to your plotOptions.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hibiscus/ec8gm8oq/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked I just added plotOptions in my file.Thank you so much!!